# How necessary are CSS3 vendor prefixes right now?

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser, vendor-prefix

I was just wondering to what extent is it still necessary to specify vendor prefixes like 'webkit', 'moz', 'ms' or 'o' in CSS these days.

If I understand correctly, opera switched to webkit, so that drops '-o-', right? IE dropped the need for '-ms-' in IE10, but do you still need it for older versions? And I'm not sure what the story is with '-moz-' right now.

Basically all my CSS3 seems to work just fine across all (up to date) browsers without specifying any prefix, so I was just wondering what is necessary and what isn't necessary as of mid 2014.

EDIT: Basically I'm just wondering does anyone have an up-to-date list of what prefixes are necessary and under what conditions are they necessary.

Comment: even if a browser stops using `-o-` for example, you have to remember people still use old browsers.

Comment: auto prefixr and caniuse.com FTW.

Comment: @Blowsie I googled it, and I disagree with you. There are a ton of OUT OF DATE articles that are giving mixed answers. I am just looking for a coherent summary for the state of prefixes right now.

Comment: @Mihey Oh, cool, caniuse.com, nice site, thanks

Comment: +1 for http://caniuse.com/

Comment: @Blowsie No, I genuinely was not familiar with the site. It's very helpful.

Comment: You disagree that people use old versions of browsers?

Comment: This has been asked several times before. Asking it again is not constructive; focus on improving the answers to existing questions if they are not satisfactory or up-to-date.

Comment: @Jukka You want me, the person who asked the question, to go and answer the same question that other people have asked, but who didn't get adequate responses? Nice logic.

Comment: @AzzyDude, the way SO works is with good questions and good answers, not via duplicates of the same question each with a varying set of answers. If you find the existing answers unsatisfactory, post comments on them (or on the existing questions) explaining what is wrong with them.

Comment: @Jukka Works well in theory, but my question is answered now, and I got it a lot faster than commenting on an old post and hoping someone eventually responds. So I guess practice is a bit different from theory.

Comment: The answer you accepted is the same as the accepted answer to the old question, so closing this as a duplicate was very adequate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build a filtered list on this web page and show all of the required prefixes.

http://caniuse.com/#comparison

Comment: "ur links not werkin" for me at least. Is it perhaps linking to an older version of Caniuse or something?

Comment: Hmm, for some reason that link just takes me to an empty caniuse.com page?

Comment: yeah, seems the linking is broken on the site. Looking for a solution

Comment: caniuse is a good resource though.

Answer (score 1):

for the most part, you may find things work great in the latest browsers without vendor prefixes. BUT I will point out 3 reasons why you might want to keep using them at least some of the time and then you decide for yourself when you think it is appropriate.

1. (as was mentioned already) Not everyone is using the most up to date browser.
2. You won't break anything by using vendor prefixes even in cases when you don't need to, so it can only improve your site and not harm it.
3. If your using prefixes (etc) from a service like http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ then it's a trivial copy-paste and you gain nothing by not using it (except perhaps a smidgen of file space)